# PHP Response line break

Tags: php, string, forms

Yes, I am mentally challenged tonight. 
If anyone could help, that'd be very cool.

I just need to add a line break to the php string of a return message after the 'out'.

PHP FILE

```
  // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
  $email_to = "m.wolf@me.com";
  $email_subject = "message submission";
  $name = $_POST['name']; // required
  $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
  $message = $_POST['message']; // required
  $email_message = "Form details below.nn";
  $email_message .= "Name: ".$name."n";
  $email_message .= "Email: ".$email_from."n";
  $email_message .= "Message: ".$message."n";
  $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."rn".
  'Reply-To: '.$email_from."rn" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
}
// return all our data to an AJAX call
echo json_encode($data);
```

JS FILE

```
scotchApp.controller('FormController',function($scope, $http) {
    // creating a blank object to hold our form information.
    //$scope will allow this to pass between controller and view
    $scope.formData = {};
    // submission message doesn't show when page loads
    $scope.submission = false;
    // Updated code thanks to Yotam
    var param = function(data) {
        var returnString = '';
        for (d in data){
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(d))
                returnString += d + '=' + data[d] + '&';
        }
        // Remove last ampersand and return
        return returnString.slice( 0, returnString.length - 1 );
    };
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'process.php',
            data : param($scope.formData), // pass in data as strings
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
        })
            .success(function(data) {
                if (!data.success) {
                    // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
                    $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
                    $scope.errorEmail = data.errors.email;
                    $scope.errorTextarea = data.errors.message;
                    $scope.submissionMessage = data.messageError;
                    $scope.submission = true; //shows the error message
                } else {
                    // if successful, bind success message to message
                    $scope.submissionMessage = data.messageSuccess;
                    $scope.formData = {}; // form fields are emptied with this line
                    $scope.submission = true; //shows the success message
                }
            });
```

I just can't seem to make it work. 
terribly entry level, I know.

If it helps: I am using php/angular/bootstrap. 
Anyway. thanks.

Comment: <br /> should do the job right, if that doesn't work you could try /n?

Comment: this just shows the tags in the automated message

Comment: Then when echoing the message the HTML is being filtered with some kind of function.

Comment: yes the messageSuccess is the 'else' in an if/else statement.

Comment: @newneub Make sure first that your script reaching the part where $data['messageSuccess']; is set. Try var_dump() variables to see their contents at certain points of script execution. And enable error reporting.

Comment: @newneub did you got any solution on this ?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be using [PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) constant and [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function:

```
<?php
$data['messageSuccess'] = 'Thanks for reaching out'.PHP_EOL.' We will contact you shortly. ';
echo nl2br($data['messageSuccess']);
?>
```

or using \n :

```
<?php
 $data['messageSuccess'] = "Thanks for reaching out.\n We will contact you shortly.";
echo nl2br($data['messageSuccess']);
?>
```

If you don't have error reporting enabled, and it seems you don't, you can do it like this:

```
<?php
// Turn off error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Report runtime errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
?>
```

Comment: These just don't work. I appreciate the help though. Nothing shows up on my form when I implement these.

Comment: I get good results with this. Maybe you should update your question with more code...

Comment: And make sure you have error reporting enabled. Add error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1); at the top of you script.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br />` or `\n` to "force" a new line. Or you can wrap your sentence into `<p>` tags like this:

```
$data['messageSuccess'] = '<p>Thanks for reaching out.</p> <p>We will contact you shortly. </p>';
```

Comment: this just shows the <p> tags in the automated message the form produces.